# findChild returns None

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I saw other people asking this question but none of what I tried worked.
I am using **PyQt 5.10.1.**

Here is python code:

```
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
view = QQuickView()
view.setSource(QUrl("module/Layout.qml"))
print(view.rootContext())
print(view.findChild(QObject, 'launcherComponent'))
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

And here is the QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import "calendar/resources" as CalendarComponent
import "weather/resources"  as WeatherComponent
import "launcher/resources" as LauncherComponent

import Test 1.0
import Weather 1.0
import Calendar 1.0
import Launcher 1.0


ApplicationWindow {
    id: appId
    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight
    visible: true
    modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
    flags: Qt.Dialog
    title: qsTr("NarcisseOS")
    color: "black"

    LauncherComponent.LauncherComponent {
        id: launcherComponentId
        objectName: launcherComponent
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

I tried everything I thought about. But this findChild function is only returning None.

I tried to reinstall PyQt5. And I tried to put the objectName property in a Rectangle object, I thought maybe a more generic one would be working. None of it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several errors:

- The `objectName` property must be a string:

---

```
LauncherComponent.LauncherComponent {
    id: launcherComponentId
    objectName: "launcherComponent"
    height: parent.height
    width: parent.width
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

- Another error is that if you are going to use `ApplicationWindow` you should not use `QQuickView` since `ApplicationWindow` creates a toplevel and `QQuickView` as well so you will have 2 toplevels and you are looking for the son of `QQuickView` but not in the `ApplicationWindow` children, so I recommend you modify your .py to:

---

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtQml import *

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load(QUrl("module/Layout.qml"))
if len(engine.rootObjects()) == 0:
    sys.exit(-1)
print(engine.rootObjects()[0].findChild(QObject, 'launcherComponent'))
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That is, you must use `QQmlApplicationEngine`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, **it worked**!
I was reading the documentation but did not find an explanation like yours. I'll do some research about this engine class.